# ReactJs compiling, not running in localhost even changing ports

Tags: localhost, port

I have a problem. Some days ago my application was running ok, but for some reason now I can't run it on localhost:3000. I even tried with the IP address, but still doesn't run. Searching for possible solutions, I tried to change the port to 80 or 4500, however, even doing that change I can't print the project in the explorer.

It's very odd, because I get the message that the code was compiled successfully.

[This is the message compilation that I get][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsIv0.png

I, however, get some warnings when I run the application:

```html
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.4 requires a peer of ajv@>=8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2 requires a peer of typescript@>= 2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mdb-react-ui-kit@3.0.0 requires a peer of react@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mdb-react-ui-kit@3.0.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mdb-react-ui-kit@3.0.0 requires a peer of @types/react@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mdb-react-ui-kit@3.0.0 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-popper@2.2.4 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 1454 packages in 3.088s
```

As far as I know. This warnings doesn't affect the application. However, I would appreciate some feedback of what other solutions I can explore to make it run.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Requesting you to share the source code of your application. Without it, it's difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Ankit_M!. I solved the problem at the end. It wasn't a bootstrap error. I was calling a proxy middleware as a property instead of as an object, so I just needed to wrap the variable in {}. Now the code is running without the localhost error. Rookie mistake :(

Comment: Glad to know you worked it out. Cheers!